# http://localhost:8080/ vs http://server_IP_address:8080/

Tags: 12.04, tomcat7

after installing tomcat7 on ubuntu.

what to do if   http://localhost:8080/    works fine but   http://server_IP_address:8080/ does not. 
what is the difference between these two?

Comment: localhost is 127.0.0.1 its a loopback. you can only access your server on the server machine itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` is redirected to 127.0.0.1 via the `lo` local loopback interface, as defined in the hosts file. (/etc/hosts) This local link will work even if the computer does not have an internet connection.

Accessing from the server IP sends a connection through the internet. Your connection would get routed to the destination (server IP) via the server's internet connection on `wlan0` or `eth0`, depending on the setup.

If the server is behind a router, you will need to forward port 8080 to the server's internal IP address, otherwise the connection will be stopped at the router. If you still can't connect, then you need to make sure that the port is open on your ISP, as well as on your computer's firewall.